# Is my code's worse time complexity is log(n)?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory, time-complexity

The method `foo` gets as a parameter a **sorted list with different numbers** and returns the count of all the occurrences such that: `i == list[i]` (where `i` is the index `0 <= i <= len(list)`).

```
def foo_helper(lst, start, end):

    if start > end:
        # end of recursion
        return 0

    if lst[end] < end or lst[start] > start:
        # no point checking this part of the list
        return 0

    # all indexes must be equal to their values
    if abs(end - start) == lst[end] - lst[start]:
        return end - start + 1

    middle = (end + start) // 2

    print(lst[start:end+1], start, middle, end)

    if lst[middle] == middle:
        #print("lst[" , middle , "]=", lst[middle])
        return 1 + foo_helper(lst, middle+1, end) + foo_helper(lst, start, middle-1)


    elif lst[middle] < middle:
        return foo_helper(lst, middle+1, end)
    else:
        return foo_helper(lst, start, middle-1)

def foo(lst):
    return foo_helper(lst, 0, len(lst)-1)
```

My question is if this code's **worst-case complexity** = log(n)?
If not, What should I do different?

Comment: Fixed the indentations.

Comment: Trying to get my head around it. Think of the graph of the identity function. We want to know where this sorted list (a strictly monotonic function) intersects the line `y = x`, considering only integer locations. Because we have a sorted list with unique elements, we have `i == list[i]` either at no place, at one place, or if there are multiple places they must be consecutive (once you're above the line you can never come back down), right?

Comment: The `lst[start:end+1]` alone takes Θ(n) time, but I suppose that's would disappear in a final version, right?

Comment: @larsmans, Yes. this is just for debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of `N` numbers, all unique, and known to be sorted, then if `list[0] == 0` and `list[N-1] == N-1`, then the uniqueness and ordering properties dictate that the entire list meets the property that `list[i] == i`. This can be determined in `O(1)` time - just check the first and last list entries.

The uniqueness and ordering properties force any list to have three separate regions - a possibly empty prefix region where `list[i] < i`, a possibly empty middle region where `list[i] == i`, and a possibly empty suffix region where `list[i] > i]`. In the general case, finding the middle region requires `O(n)` time - a scan from the front to find the first index where `list[i] == i`, and a scan from the back to find the last such index (or you could do both with one single forward scan). Once you find those, you are guaranteed by uniqueness and ordering that all the indexes in between will have the same property...

Edit: As pointed out by @tobias_k below, you could also do a binary search to find the two end points, which would be `O(log n)` instead of `O(n)`. This would be the better option if your inputs are completely general.

Comment: +1 for the observation, but couldn't you do binary search with O(log(n)) to find the borders of the three regions?

Comment: @tobias_k Doh... why, yes you could... Whether that's the better option in the long run would depend on what your expected inputs are. If the prefix/suffix regions are almost always empty or at least quite small, the linear search could actually outperform binary search.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment trying to think about this problem. Consider of the graph of the identity function, which represents the indices. We want to know where this sorted list (a strictly monotonic function) intersects the line representing the indices `y = x`, considering only integer locations. I think you should be able to find this in O(n) time (as commented it seems binary search for the intersection bounds should work), though I need to look at your code more closely to see what it's doing.

Because we have a sorted list with unique elements, we have `i == list[i]` either at no place

[image]

at one place

[image]

or if there are multiple places they must be consecutive (once you're above the line you can never come back down)

[image]

Code used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.unique(np.random.randint(-25, 50, 50))
indices = range(len(a))
plt.scatter(indices, indices, c='b')
plt.scatter(indices, a, c='r')
plt.show()
```